# Как шифровать кириллицу в кодировке UTF-8?

Tags: mcrypt, php, utf-8, шифрование

```
function myxor($text, $key){
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

 for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($text);) 
 {
     for($j=0;$j<mb_strlen($key);$j++, $i++)
     {
          $outText .= $text{$i} ^ $key{$j};
     }
 }
return $outText;}
```

Есть такой код. Все бы хорошо, но шифрует и дешифрует он только латиницу и цифры. Как шифровать кириллицу в кодировке UTF-8?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `strlen` вместо `mb_strlen`.